# gpg fails to find key to elpa archive

Tags: package-repositories, gpg

I'm getting this error while trying download a package from ELPA:

```
 Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
 No public key for 474F05837FBDEF9B created at 2018-11-28T14:10:03-0800 using DSA
 Command output:
 gpg: keyblock resource '/c/apps/emacs-25.3_1/bin/c:/users/myuserid/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/pubring.kbx': No such file or directory
 gpg: Signature made Wed Nov 28 14:10:03 2018 PST
 gpg:                using DSA key CA442C00F91774F17F59D9B0474F05837FBDEF9B
 gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I've been doing some clean up in my init file but I don't see how it could have impacted this.  In a way it's a good thing because it's a good opportunity to setup gpg but it's not working for me.  I used `customize-apropos` to set these values:

```
  '(epg-gpg-home-directory "C:/Program Files/Git")
  '(epg-gpg-program "gpg.exe --homedir /c/users/myuserid/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg")
```

I'm using the `gpg` that comes with my git client.  However, no matter what I set it doesn't seem to care, it still has the invalid path the keys.

What could be causing these gpg variables to not be respected??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this issue. I solved it using the following steps in order:

1. Installing [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/index.html)
2. Make sure that the folder **c:/Progra~2/GnuPG/bin** is on your path before any other installed versions of the GnuPG executables (in my case, I had it installed via msys2).

Note that *Progra~2* expands to "Program Files (x86)" on my system (I am using the 64 bit version of Windows, you might need to substitute *Progra~1* in the string if you are using a 32 bit version of Windows).

Comment: Seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: See also:
The gnu elpa gpg key has expired in september, this seems to be the solution:

gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
source: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/bn6k1y/updating_gnu_elpa_keys/

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue using above solutions in tandem.

I changed the `package-gnupghome-dir` as suggested. This got me partway there. I then got a different error, `Can't check signature: No public key`. So, I ran

`$ gpg --homedir /c/Users/micha/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40`

`gpg: key 066DAFCB81E42C40: public key "GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2019) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>" imported`

and the issue was resolved. Thanks, @preetpalS and @jürgen-a-erhard!

Comment: This worked for me on Windows using emacs build 27.2

Answer (score 2):

Emacs' package infrastructure uses its own variable for GPG, package-gnupghome-dir.  For me (and, obviously, you here) it failed because Emacs' filename functions don't see the path as an *absolute* path (see the "/c:/users/" in the "keyblock" line).  Thus, it does what it does with relative paths, it finds them (or tries to) in the current directory.

Change the beginning of package-gnupghome-dir from "C:/" to "/c/"… that *should* fix it, but I only tested it on my (msys2) system.  YMMV ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I could only mitigate this issue by running emacs via a Windows command shell (or powershell). To clarify, I installed emacs via MSYS2, but I always encounter the `pubring.kbx': No such file or directory` error if I run emacs via an MSYS22 shell.

This may introduce other issues, but I can refresh my package contents, and install new packages. My `.emacs.d/` seems to be in `<windows home directory>/Appdata/Roaming/`.

(Emacs 27.2 build 1 on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on GNU Emacs 27.2 for Windows, when I performed a `M-x list-packages`. In my case, I've both GNU Emacs 27.2 for Windows and MSYS2. I only have this issue under the Windows version.

The gnupg path for Windows version is under `c:/users/userid/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/`.
The gnupg path for MSYS2 version is under `/home/userid/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg`. A `pubring.kbx` file (and other files) is found under MSYS2 version, but no files under Windows version.

I solved this issue in 2 steps: -

1. adding `(setq package-gnupghome-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg")` to my `.emacs` in Windows version. `.emacs` should be found under `c:/users/userid/AppData/Roaming/`. If not found, you can create one and append the `(setq...)` above.
2. copy the `pubring.kbx` file from MSYS2 version to `c:/users/userid/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/`.